# how to get rid of the ghc dependency of xmonad-mate?

Tags: haskell, xmonad, mate

I am on fedora, and use the `xmonad-mate` package. This depends on `ghc`, and I don't want this, because I have (newer) ghc installed anyway, so it just wastes space on disk, and time/downloads on upgrades.

Why do I use the package at all? Because it seems the foolproof way to get everything configured, and have it as option in `gdm`, and start `mate-panel`, etc.

I understand the dependency on ghc (needed to re-compile .xmonad/xmonad.hs) but I do want to side-track it. Like, provide a dummy `ghc` (and `ghc-xmonad`) package? But then - if that's more cumbersome than isolating the config files ...

Comment: It looks like `xmonad-mate` is just a configuration file - right? So just build `xmonad` using the ghc you already have. Do you know how to manually build an application from Hackage?

Comment: sure I know regularily build xmonad from hackage, and install/compile ghc. But where to put what config files to please gdm and mate is a complete mystery to me...

Comment: according to [this](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/rpminfo?rpmID=7624204) `xmonad-mate` consists of a single file placed in the directory /usr/share/xsessions. Does that help?

Comment: well, plus (at least) /usr/bin/xmonad-start is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I would go to this page:

http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=757093

find your architecture, and click on all the **(info)** links. On each info page at the bottom there is a list of file contained in the package.

Just go through each one and see what files are placed where when the package is installed.